# GC slows down spark job to a halt

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, garbage-collection

I am running a pretty simple spark job which reads in many s3 files one by one and call a map/filter job on the RDD and write the results out to another s3. Another words, there is first a for loop, inside each loop, there is one sc call to read, process, then write steps.

The paces is abnormally slow, even though each file sizes is small compared to node size and number (500 MB running inside 8 nodes each w 10 GB of executor memory).

in the worker node stdout log, I see continuous lines like this
[GC2015-10-16T22:31:39.567+0000: [ParNew: 272655K->19K(306688K), 0.0292600 secs] 467995K->195361K(10451712K), 0.0293570 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]

seems the workers are jump being GC'ed to death. Why should this happen?

Comment: How many of these gc lines per say ten second interval? At about 1 / 10 seconds this would be about right (1% of total cpu).

Answer (score 1):

not sure exactly how many per second, but I found a solution which is reasonable.

In this case, a new RDD is generated per file, which triggers collection of prev RDD's. I rewrote the code so that the RDD is a var, and reuse the same variable for each cycle of the loop. Now, I still see the GC lines, but the throughput is easily 10 times faster.